# Sobrecarga en mi página web

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Estoy teniendo problemas con el tiempo de respuesta de mi página web, ya que estoy intentando refrescar una imagen usando el siguiente script y quiero suponer que es debido a que genera una sobrecarga:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $('#speed_png').load('file.php'); 
    }, 3000);
});
```

Lo único que hago con este script es recargar periódicamente una imagen en la web, pero al tercer o cuarto ciclo de carga la pagina deja de responder. Me interesa tener este código ya que de el depende que imagen se visualiza en la web.

```
    <img style="width: 30%;" id="speed_png" src="">
```

Por el momento mi web apenas tiene 50 líneas de código, no creo que esto afecte demasiado, así que supongo que hay alguna cosa del script que se me escapa. El hardware de mi equipo es suficientemente bueno como para aguantar el servidor web.

¿Alguna idea de por que la recarga de esta imagen satura la web?

Imagen de la pestaña **network** en el navegador tras el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El método que usas parece correcto. ¿El problema también aparece si aumentas el periodo del setInterval?

Comment: Si, al aumentar el tiempo, a 10000 por ejemplo, el problema persiste.

Comment: tal vez venga de tu php y en como tengas ahi las cosas

Comment: El archivo `php` solo hace una consulta a la base de datos y imprime el resultado.

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir en tu pregunta la pestaña *Network” de las Herramientas de Desarrollo del navegador? Donde se observen las recargas.

Comment: @Sal hecho, lo he añadido una captura.

Comment: Intenta hacerlo por ajax o fetch

Comment: @JoseAntonio como se realiza la implementación entonces?

Answer (score 1):

Me preguntabas por la implementación y sería algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        fetch('file.php')
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then( (data) => {
              document.querySelector('#speed_png').setAttribute('src', data.img);
            });
    }, 3000);
});
```

No se como tengas el PHP, pero tendría que devolver la ubicación de la imagen.

Comment: Inicialmente tenía ideado el programa para obtener el valor INT desde el `php`, una vez obtenido, en un código usando `js` realizo los cálculos para luego mostrar la imagen. Esto puede causar el error de sobrecarga?

Comment: Sería mejor verlo en código a ver como lo tienes. Por que no lo haces todo en el php?

Comment: Desconocía la posibilidad de actualizar una imagen de una web sin actualizar todo el contenido. En mi anterior pregunta esta el código por si quieres echar un vistazo!

Comment: No está el código PHP